# React Redux cant read nested values in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I know I am missing something incredibly obvious that likely has to do with Immutable.js/React/Redux.

I have a method like this...

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state.test));
    //prints all nested properties and objects of state.test
    //but when I do something like this I get "undefined"
    console.log(state.test.someProp);

    return {...}
}
```

Why is it that I see an object with all the nested objects and properties, but I am unable to access them. In this method my desire is to be able to pull something out of Redux state (raw API response), and create a new object which I put on my props. This requires me to read through nested properties and objects in state.test.

Why can't I access these values? Is this a bad idea? Should I not put a somewhat deep API response directly into Redux?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `state` look like? Is it an instance of some Immutable.JS class? Is so you might need to use library methods to access the props `state.getIn(['test', 'someProp'])`. Hard to say exactly w/o [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I believe it is Immutable.JS. I may have time to update my question later. get('someProp') works....I may need to do repeated get calls. Not sure

Comment: You could also use `state.toJS()` to exract all state value as POJO if you need to. But this might be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a moment for the state object to be populated by redux.

If you call it before it shows up you will get undefined.

Render it conditionally to solve this issue.

`state.test && state.test.someProp`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the rendering side of things. My understanding is that when the Redux state is updated mapStateToProps is called. As I mentioned, I see all the values I want to see in my first console.log(), when I try to print out an individual property immediately after it is 'undefined'

Comment: you're saying that console logging it conditionally does not work?

Comment: That is correct. The value is there, but I can't access/read it.